# How can I zero out some values in a set

Tags: matlab

Let say I have a hundreds of wavelet coefficients obtained after wavelet decomposition..now I want to zero out the smallest 10%  coefficients
How can I do it in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combime 'sort', 'floor' and 'length' commands; let's say your numbers are stored in a vector 'a':

```
b=sort(a);
b=b(1,floor(length(a)/10))=0;
```

You might want to/need to invoke 'abs(b)' before the first line if your ordering criterion disregards the sign.

Answer (score 2):

if your  wavelet coefficients are in a vector or a matrix `c`, first lets sort from smallest elements

```
[sc ind]=sort(c(:));
```

then zero the first 10%:

```
c(ind(1:round(numel(sc)*0.1)))=0;
```

this code will work both for 1D and 2D cases (actually this will work for the N-th dimensional case too)

Answer (score 1):

You could first take the average of all of the elements of the vector/matrix using the mean() command.

"help mean" would be better at explaining exactly what it does than I. You could then run a for loop to run through the entire array. In there, you'd have an if statement that looked something like

if matrix(i,j) <= (your previously calculated mean)/5

matrix(i,j) = 0

end

This is my first ever reply on StackExchange so let me know if I made any terrible errors.